# AutoRefresh Application: Compare old model with new one

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an application that will be auto-updated after X seconds.

When the controller is accessed firstly, I load a model in a partial view. There's no change (there isn't any user interaction with the view), after some seconds I need to make another request to the database to compare the old data (sent before, firstly) with the new data obtained after this request.

Whats the best way to keep my old model data to compare with the new one ? Maybe you guys can suggest me something to avoid sending the model back to the controller (had problems on handling the model into `data` ajax variable), since it won't be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use one of the shared container: cookies, local storage or session.

[cookie\local storage - if you data is not secure]

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Compare(MyModel model)
{
    var oldModel = Session["MyModel"];
    if (oldModel == null)
    {
        // initialization
        Session["MyModel"] = model;
    }
    else
    {
        // second request
        AnyCompareActions(newModel: model, oldModel: oldModel);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```